# Subplot in existing R plot

Tags: r, subplot

I have a plot as shown below. To this plot i would like to add a similar kind of line plot somewhere within the plot (bottomright or bottomleft). The command for the subplot i am using is

```
plot( 1:121, sample(1:121),type='l' )
```

It plots right on the top of the first one. I need it as a small plot either at the bottomleft or bottomright. COuld someone help to do this in R?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)

set.seed(42)
plot(rnorm(100), runif(100))

par(new=TRUE, oma=c(3,1,1,2))
layout(matrix(1:4,2))

plot(rnorm(100), runif(100), col="blue", xlab="", ylab="")

par(op)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! I am looking for a similar kind of thing. But, is there a way so that the coordinates of one plot does not mix-up over the other plot. The subplot can also be located outside the main plot.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the parameter `new` to `TRUE`, the canvas will not be cleaned before the next plotting command:

```
par( new= TRUE )
```

I leave it to your ingenuity to create a suitable white background and position the new plot :-) Hint: take a look at the `omd` parameter in the manual for `par`.