# Attach two figures in R

Tags: r

I would like to have the highlighted part of this figure as a separate figure inside the main figure.   How can I do this in R?[image]

```
     lin <- data.frame(x = c(0:6), y = c(0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 3.1, 5, 4.9, 6.2))
     linm <- lm(y ~ x, data = lin, subset = 2:4)
     plot(y ~ x, data = lin)
     abline(linm)
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about what exactly you want the expected result to look like?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17696562/1412059

Comment: I need a subplot from x = 0 to 3 and y=0 to 3, in side the existing plot.

Comment: Yes. I want the shaded region as a subplot inside the main plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer but I believe this is a duplicate as Roland pointed out.  All I did was take the original plot and set the `ylim`/`xlim` to `c(0, 3)` in the subplot using the link Roland provided:

```
op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)

lin <- data.frame(x = c(0:6), y = c(0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 3.1, 5, 4.9, 6.2))
linm <- lm(y ~ x, data = lin, subset = 2:4)
plot(y ~ x, data = lin)
abline(linm)

par(new=TRUE, oma=c(3,1,1,2))
layout(matrix(1:4,2))

lin <- data.frame(x = c(0:6), y = c(0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 3.1, 5, 4.9, 6.2))
linm <- lm(y ~ x, data = lin, subset = 2:4)
plot(y ~ x, data = lin, ylim=c(0,3), xlim=c(0, 3))
abline(linm)

par(op)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Just If I want to change the position of new subplot in upper regression line , what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a shaded region, try something like:

```
lin <- data.frame(x = c(0:6), y = c(0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 3.1, 5, 4.9, 6.2))
linm <- lm(y ~ x, data = lin, subset = 2:4)
plot(y ~ x, data = lin)
abline(linm)
rect(0,0,3,3, col=rgb(.5,.5,.5,.5),border=NA)
```

[image]